# React & Webpack - Project set up for multi page application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm starting up a react project (using create-react-app) which will have multi "one page" components within. So, I assume, the directory structure for development would look like below:

```
/Project
  /node_modules
  /public
  /src
    /components
      /layout
      /popup
      ...
    /pages
      /dashboard
        index.js
      /profiles
        index.js
        ...
```

If I build the project without any modification, it would bundle all the source code and resources under one directory. Well, that's not going to work for what I am trying to do for this project. I need to have different bundles for each page. So the bundles under the /public folder should look something similar to the following structure:

```
/Project
  ...
  /build
    /dashboard
      /static
        /css
        /js
        /media
      index.html
    /profiles
      /static
        /css
        /js
        /media
      index.html
  ...
```

I looked at "Code Splitting" in webpack documentation. There's a good example with different entry points but I couldn't adapt it. How can I achieve the desired setup with webpack and react?

Comment: one option: create an entry for each "page" component's index. another option: dynamic import()

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use React code splitting, using [React Loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable), no need to modify Webpack configuration.

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: Yeah, do this if you can. That's some awesome stuff

Comment: The question is not using dynamic loading. From webpack documentation: "...A dynamically loaded module is not an entry point. Simple rule: one entry point per HTML page. SPA: one entry point, MPA: multiple entry points..." . I have come as far as ejecting the app and modifying the webpack production config. It seems like creating a separate build function is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is late to answer but I was facing the same issue and found a simple solution that I wanted to share.

I followed these steps:

- Multiple entry points in webpack for each page
- dynamic output bundle names for each entry point
- Multiple html output files with different filenames using HtmlWebpackPlugin, also define particular chunks (bundles),

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ filename: 'index.html',template: './src/index.html' ,chunks:['page1']})
```

- Each template for each html page will have one div with particular id lets say root which is used by react app to render its app on dom.
- Now every js entry point for each page will have

```
    ReactDOM.render(<Page1 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Webpack docs on [Multiple Entry files](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)

And have a look at the examples in [webpack's github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points)

Comment: I did but how to adapt it for a react app? That's the question.